# Recover table back from pdf document created with latex

Tags: pdf, tabularray, odsfile

I recently converted a libreoffice spreadsheet to a pdf using latex and the odsfile package like this (using lualatex). The table contained numbers with comma as decimal separator.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}  

\usepackage{odsfile}

\tabletemplate{booktabs}{%
\begin{tblr}{-{coltypes}}
\toprule -{colheading} \midrule -{content}\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
}


\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}

\SetTblrInner{row{1}={font=\bfseries}}

\includespread[file=myfile.ods,range=a4:p20,template=booktabs,columns=head]

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I accidently deleted `myfile.ods`. Then I tried to copy and paste the table to libreoffice calc from evince, but didn't succeed.

So is there any clever way to get the table back, maybe taking advantage of how it was created (see source code above)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I don't know if knowing how the pdf was created helps to get better results, but [tabula](https://tabula.technology/) should work quite well for that type of problem.